# cannot exit from while loop

Tags: ruby, while-loop

My code is stuck within *while-loop*. It keeps looping back to the *Backup_power* (refer to the image below). 
[image]

```
lowest = 38
puts 'Read Temperature:'
t = gets.chomp.to_f

if(t < lowest)
 lowest = t
end
while t<=80 || bpower=='on'
  puts 'Enter backup power (on/off):'
  bpower = gets.chomp

  if(t<50)
    puts 'Normal mode of operation'
  else
    if(t<=80 || bpower=='on')       
      puts 'On the fan'
    else
      puts'Turn off equipment'
    end
  end
  puts lowest
end
```

Comment: Please tell us what you're trying to do. Show us some code and explain where you are struggling.

Comment: i had inserted the picture

Comment: "Can somebodyy help me?" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: i had already edit the question. Theres a link beside it for the program that i am required to do

Comment: You've posted your code. Now can you say where in the code you're getting the problem. Is there an error message? What does it say?

Comment: it keeps looping back to 'Enter backup power (on/off):'. but I want to loop back to the start point. there a link image for the program i required to do

Comment: Are you required to use a while loop?

Comment: Yes. SInce i had only learn that for loop

Comment: @AjiAyi : Of course it does. The "Enter..." output is the first statement in the loop, so it is executed every time the loop is looping. This is the very purpose of a loop. If you don't want any repetition, don't write a loop.

Comment: @AjiAyi : Since you are only learning to program: I recommend you not to use flowcharts as the one you have linked to, as a base for developing a program: A flowchart allows to jump from one location to an arbitrary different location, and you can not model this in Ruby anyway. A flowchart **can** be transformed in a way so that such unstructured jumps are eliminated, but this is difficult for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there!
The problem is you did not include the *Read Temperature* inside the loop. So how do you intend to read the new temperature?

I will give you a hint:

```
lowest = 38
t=0
bpower="on"

while t<=80 || bpower=='on'
  Read Temperature
```

Comment: hmmmm i am should i puts:Read temperature below the while loop?

Comment: well, according to your design. Nice flowchart by the way, easy to understand.